# How to enable/disable cloudwatch event attached to lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I've tried using the Cloudwatch Events/EventBridge JS SDK to enable/disable the rule which does work on the global scale. However, the cloudwatch event that is attached to my lambda does not change in state.

I'm looking to have a lambda that I can enable/disable the CRON aspect of. I see in the AWS UI there is a toggle to enable/disable the cloudwatch event but I'm not able to figure out how to access this functionality with the JS SDK.

toggle of AWS cloudwatch event:

[image: toggle of AWS cloudwatch event]

Comment: "my lambda does not change in state" - have you actually checked on the rule itself? Lambda console sometimes does not update properly. Maybe it all works, but lambda does not show it?

Comment: You are correct, the rule took about 1-5 minutes to take full effect. The cloudwatch rule on my lambda itself stays enabled even if I disable the rule globally but for my use case thats fine. Im only using this rule in one lambda.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: I added answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the problem was that lambda console sometimes shows **incorrect associations**. The solution was to actually perform a check and test the rules. The test showed that the **rule was correctly disabled**, even though the console shows otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To disable this you want to look at the event source mapping.

In the JS SDK there is a function named [updateEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#updateEventSourceMapping-property) which is responsible for this.

One of the params you can pass in is `Enabled` which if set to false will set a disabled flag.

To get the UUID of the event source take a look at the [listEventSourceMappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listEventSourceMappings-property) function. You can filter by FunctionName and/or EventSourceArn (in this case the Arn of the CloudWatch Event).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unforunatly it looks like you cant get the UUID of the event source if its not 
Amazon Kinesis 
Amazon DynamoDB Streams 
Amazon Simple Queue Service
From the listEventSourceMappings